# How to use divided projects in Spring Boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Welcome,

I'm begginer in Spring (also in Spring Boot). I create four maven projects in Eclipse:

- my-persistance
- my-presentation
- my-webservices
- my-main

I have assumed every part of program will be store in one of these special projects. For example: html, jsp files will be store in "my-presentation", also like Spring @Controller files. Projects that aren't "my-main" should be build earlier and store in local maven repository [via 'mvn clean install']to add them to "my-main" war package.

I just read one Spring Boot guide:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

It works when all elements are in one project. I want move Web Controller to "my-presentation" and class Application to "my-main". Of course it isn't working. Could it be possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how to work with Maven and multiple module.
Basically, you create parent pom.xml, and in each submodule (my-persistance, my-presentation, etc.) you create submodule pom.xml, that refer to parent pom.xml.
I have a similar configuration in [my example project](https://github.com/d-sauer/TechStack), you can check pom.xml files

Comment: Ok, it doesn't help literally, but i have had change conception of project and implement yours idea. +1